# Instances in the Unity Profiler Timeline

Tags: unity, rendering, profiling, profiler

What do Instances mean when you click on an operation in the Timeline section of Unity Profiler?

*In this example:*

> **Total: 11.90 ms (10 Instances)**

[image]